# Can't resolve './server.component.css'

Tags: angular, angular-material

I created the following component:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: 'app-server',
    template: `<h1>Some Information</h1>`,
    styleUrls: ['./server.component.css']
})
export class Servercomponent{

}
```

When I try to compile my app, I get the following error:

```
ERROR in ./src/app/server/server.component.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './server.component.css' in 'E:\Angular\angularapp\angularapp\src\app\server'
i ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.
```

Do you have any idea what the problem could be?

Comment: `server.component.css` should be location in the same place that `server.component.ts` is located, if its located then restart the angular server

Comment: You're welcome, do answer your own question and give green tick to close this question :)